# Difference between MLE and general linear model

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, bayesian

> Briefly discuss how the model expressed by (7) differs from the general linear model.

$$\log(T_i) = a_0 + a_1 x_{1i} + a_2 x_{2i} + \sigma \log(\varepsilon_i) \tag 7$$

Since MLE  has $n$ independent and identically distributed observations with 
an unknown probability density functions, this (7) does not have a form of $Y = XB + U$ they differ?

I am not sure how the model $(7)$ differs from a general linear model.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Usually "MLE" means "maximum likelihood estimator", but that is not what you mean here. Can you explain what you mean by that?

Comment: Apologies for the late comment. (7) is a Frequentist based MLE , having trouble finding the difference between frequentist based MLE and the general linear model.